# How to work with AJAX CRUD on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a standart **index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table" id="payments">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th>Show</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Destroy</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= payment.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %></td>
        <td><%= payment.description %></td>
        <td><%= payment.amount %></td>
        <td><%= payment.comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', payment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_payment_path(payment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', payment, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "delete_payment" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to 'New Payment', new_payment_path %></br></br>
```

I need to implement all CRUD actions via AJAX. No thoughts how to deal with it. I've added 
to my form but I need somehow to render my _form on index.html.erb when user click on **New payment** or **Edit** buttons.

```
<%= form_for(payment, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

I implemented AJAX for destroy action by creating **destroy.js.erb**

```
$('.delete_payment').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: You've added `remote: true` to what form? I see you've added it to your `link_to 'Destroy'`... All `remote: true` does is tell your destroy action to render a javascript template as a response rather than an html response. So in `app/views/payments/` you would add `destroy.js.erb` and put javascript code in there.

Comment: @BigRon edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will describe the overall approach to you, and hopefully the specifics to your implementation will make sense as you implement.
lets start with the destroy, as thats the easiest.

1. add remote: true to the link, thats perfect.
2. create controller action that consumes this delete request
   (payments_controller)

   `def destroy
    @payment = Payment.find params[:id]
    if @payment.destroy
      render 'destroy'
    end
   end`
3. create a view in `views/payments/` called `destroy.js.erb`
4. in your original index view, add `<tr id='payment_<%= payment.id %>'>` definition to your tr, so that every row has an ID in the dom which it is assosociated with
5. change your destroy.js.erb to

   `$(document).ready(function(){
     $('tr#payment_<%= @payment.id %>').fadeOut('slow');
   });`

once you have destroy working, create and edit follow the same approach. Where create adds a TR, and edit replaces an old TR with a new TR.

hope this helps

Comment: I have a question: how can I work with my _form.html.erb? I need it to appear on index.html.erb

Comment: your create call will render 'create' which renders /views/payments/create.js.erb, now in your create.js.erb render the 'form' partial which is in the same directory, and populate it with the data. then use javascript to dump the result of that to the DOM

Comment: I created edit.js.erb and populated it with $("#edit_payment").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))%>");  Now I get the form on my page but after editing it redirect me to my payment page.

Comment: so the submit of your form is not handled properly. an edit form should go to the update method. create an update method in the controller and make sure you hit it after pressing the submit button in your edit form. (if you don't, you need to adjust the form definition parameters until it hits the right method) then add update.js.erb which will replace the old row with the new data, or just re-render the index page as that will show the new data already.

Comment: in my controller (update action) I have
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was updated' }. What shoukd I write in update.js.erb?

Comment: your redirect is wrong, you need a render 'update' instead of that whole redirect. and update.js.erb needs to do something like $('tr#payment_<%= @payment.id %>').html(" NEW HTML OF THE LINE ITEM HERE")

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created two files
**new.js.erb** (which hides my 'New payment' button and show form)

```
$("#new_payment_btn").hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

**create.js.erb** (which hides form and show button)

```
$("#new_payment").remove();
$("#new_payment_btn").show();
```

Now I can add items via form but still no idea how to refresh the table: still need reload page to new payments appear in the table.

Comment: so the best way to refresh the whole table, is indeed a full redirect (which re-renders). you dont have to do that though - by putting the definition of the table into a partial, and rendering it over into the dom from the create.js.erb file. (you can also render it into the index.html.erb to avoid duplication, decent approach)

Comment: I created a partial and inserted table there, then in create.js.erb I call $('body').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'payments_table') %>"); and in index.html.erb I wrote <%= render 'payments_table' %> and it's duplicated.

Comment: yeah, the create needs to remove the old one before it adds a new one, since you are replacing it entirely :)